# Get all the raw data; keys, values within the { } related to the value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a response with many 'elements' in "content" looking like this.

For the example I've cut it down to 3 'elements' with each 3 items:

```
{

  "code": 0,

  "data": {

    "content": [

      {

        "userid": 1,

        "username": "user1",

        "city": "city1", 

      },

      {

        "userid": 2,

        "username": "user2",

        "city": "city2", 

      },
     {

        "userid": 3,

        "username": "user3",

        "city": "city3", 

      }

    ],

    "number": 0,

    "size": 0,

    "totalElements": 3

  },

  "message": "SUCCESS",

  "serverTime": 1611071504886,

  "success": true

}
```

How do I look for e.g.

if userid == 2

then get/print all the raw data; keys, values within the { } related to the userid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your response is like you show, then one possible, yet a bit dirty, solution could be:

```
x = {
  "code": 0,
  "data": {
    "content": [
      {
        "userid": 1,
        "username": "user1",
        "city": "city1", 
      },
      {
        "userid": 2,
        "username": "user2",
        "city": "city2", 
      },
     {
        "userid": 3,
        "username": "user3",
        "city": "city3", 
      }
    ],
    "number": 0,
    "size": 0,
    "totalElements": 3
  },
  "message": "SUCCESS",
  "serverTime": 1611071504886,
  "success": True
}

for i in range(len(x['data']['content'])):
    if (x['data']['content'][i]).get('userid') == 2:
        print(x['data']['content'][i])
```

`print(x['data']['content'][i])` gives:

```
{'userid': 2, 'username': 'user2', 'city': 'city2'}
```

Another alternate solution, similar to the above one, but a bit neater is to extract the list and then loop over it:

```
a = x['data']['content'] # <-- gets the list and assigns it to variable a

for i in range(len(a)):
    if (a[i]).get('userid') == 2:
        print(a[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

First you would need to iterate over the dicts inside and content, then you can use `if` to filter it:

```
for x in output['content']:
   if x.get('userid',None) == 2:
      print(x)
```

Comment: A better answer would be using the get method, since the get method don’t raise a `KeyError` if there is no key.